# Using Java AspectJ to count

Tags: java, aspectj

I need to use AspectJ to implement a counter in Java for a school project.  Otherwise I would do this differently.  I need the aspect to log a count every time a function is called and then retrieve that count in the UI.  I can't get java or the aspect to see the same variables.  The code below works locally but the Java classes cannot see count or bill no matter where I put them.  How can I make the class be able to see the aspect or vise versa?

```
public aspect calcBill
{   before(): execution(* *calc() )
   {   count++;
       bill = count * .03;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you mandated to maintain the count and/or bill in the aspect?

Comment: put the counter as a parameter of the java class youre aspecting and add a method to increase it (i.e `increaseCounter()`). Then add a JoinPoint parameter to the "before" aspect. this way you can call for example: `joinpoint.getThis().increaseCounter()`